# Cant log in with user credentials using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, node-modules

I'm trying to implement the following code, but something is not working. Here is the code:

```
login_data = {
  'appActionToken': 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA', 
  'appAction': 'SIGNIN',
  'openid.return_to': 'ape:BBBBBBBBBBBB',
  'prevRID': 'ape:CCCCCCCCCCCCCC',
  'workflowState': 'DDDDDDDDDDD',
  'email': 'example@sample.com',
  'create': 0,
  'password': '******',
  'metadata1': 'EEEEEEEEEEEEE',
};

axios({
  url: 'https://example.com/login',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: login_data
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log('Authenticated');
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error on Authentication');
});
```

Chrome sends all data which is in login_data to server to authenticate but when I am trying to make auth post it is not working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you need to be sending a POST request, not a GET in your axios call. Add `method: 'post',` to your axios options.  And, you may need to encode the data properly yourself.  See the axios doc for details.

Comment: it still not working, I would really appreciate if you could show me example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookie to login too. Login your account and get your cookie.

Edit all key's values of 'headers' dictionary

```
axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'your url for web scraping',
    headers: {
        Cookie: 'Paste all your cookie here',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': 0,
        'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
        'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding,X-Amzn-CDN-Cache,X-Amzn-AX-Treatment,User-Agent',
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(`Authenticated with status code: ${response.status}!`);
})
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error on Authentication');
    });
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your axios call to use 'post' instead of the default 'get' method. Something like this:

```html
login_data = {
 'appActionToken': 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA', 
 'appAction': 'SIGNIN',
 'openid.return_to': 'ape:BBBBBBBBBBBB',
 'prevRID': 'ape:CCCCCCCCCCCCCC',
 'workflowState': 'DDDDDDDDDDD',
 'email': 'example@sample.com',
 'create': 0,
 'password': '******',
 'metadata1': 'EEEEEEEEEEEEE',
};

axios.post('https://example.com/login', login_data, {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }})
.then(function(response) {
console.log('Authenticated');
})
 .catch(function(error) {
console.log('Error on Authentication');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Daniel. Should I post all formdata which Chrome send to get logged in?